# Google Calendar: Different colors/labels according to who add events

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api, organization

Hope you all are going well!

I'm trying to organize a Google Calendar for different companies: they're going to propose different events to the same audience and they asked me for a Google Calendar to keep track of everything.

I'd like to know if there's a way to separate events based on users that add them

IE:
Admin_1 add Event_1
Admin_2 add Event_2
Admin_1 add Event_3
Admin_3 add Event_4
Admin_3 add Event_5

I'd like 
Event_1 and Event_3 to have the same color or a label like "Admin_1: EVENT NAME".

The same for Event_4 and Event_5, created by Admin_3

Do you know how to do something like that or even if it is possible?

Thank you all for reading and answering!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, just provide the `colorid` parameter when adding an event. You can retrieve the list of colours from the [colors endpoint](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/colors/get).

Here is a sample code for getting the list of colors:

```
$colors = $service->colors->get();

// Print available calendarListEntry colors.
foreach ($colors->getCalendar() as $key => $color) {
  print "colorId : {$key}\n";
  print "  Background: {$color->getBackground()}\n";
  print "  Foreground: {$color->getForeground()}\n";
}
// Print available event colors.
foreach ($colors->getEvent() as $key => $color) {
  print "colorId : {$key}\n";
  print "  Background: {$color->getBackground()}\n";
  print "  Foreground: {$color->getForeground()}\n";
}
```

You can also check this [Google Calendar v3 events color](https://eduardopereira.pt/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/google_calendar_api_event_color_chart.png).

Hope this helps.